# Cannot assign to 'let' value, object declared in object in Objective-C file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I declared new `NSString` object `stateId` in h. file and add bridge to Swift project.

Now I want to change the value in Swift file but I get the error above

> "Cannot assign to 'let' value":

Declared in objective c file:

```
NSString *stateId;
```

In swift file:

```
stateId = "aaa"
```

What is I miss here?

Comment: `let` is `const` you need `var`

Comment: Where to write var? its declared in h file.

Comment: on variable delectation

Comment: How? remember its Objective c file.
Show me example. please

Comment: Do you use word `extern` in h-file?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of stateId in  the .h file?

Comment: No, how and where to use it?
The definition is: NSString *stateId;

Comment: It should be `extern NSString *stateId;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Ramkumar stated in a comment in his answer, NSString is not mutable so you can't change it's value just like that in Swift, so try changing in your .h file

```
NSString *stateId;
```

to:

```
NSMutableString *stateId;
```

and now in your .swift file you can do:

```
stateId = "the value you want"
```

It is stated in the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)

> An immutable string is a text string that is defined when it is created and subsequently cannot be changed. An immutable string is implemented as an array of Unicode characters (in other words, a text string). To create and manage an immutable string, use the NSString class. To construct and manage a string that can be changed after it has been created, use NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

> In Swift there is Two Ways Of Variable Declarations.

- 1) if You Decleare a variable That Value Never Changed

let aConsatant = 1

Here aConsatant value Never Changed . if You Trying to modify . compiler will give Error.

- 2) if You Decleare a variable That Value  Changed later Then Decleare Like

  var aVariable = 1

if yoou want change this value you change it . There is no Error.

```
aVariable = 5
```

No Error .

Comment: Again, i declared the object in objective c file.

Comment: you decleared  The definition is: NSString *stateId; so Swift under stand that it is a constant string . so decleare NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

You should write in h-file:

```
extern NSString *stateId;
```

and in some m-file:

```
NSString* stateId;
```

This pattern is common for objective-c not just swift when you want define project's global variable.

With your's original code you would get `duplicate symbol stateId` linking error anyway.